# Css removing margin or padding in columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

removing column padding or margins to create a tiling effect using bootstrap 3

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="hexagon-wrapper hex_size">
        <div class="hexagon">
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="hexagon-wrapper hex_size">
        <div class="hexagon">
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>  
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="hexagon-wrapper hex_size">
        <div class="hexagon">
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>

  //row 2
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="hexagon-wrapper hex_size">
        <div class="hexagon">
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="hexagon-wrapper hex_size">
        <div class="hexagon">
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>  
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="hexagon-wrapper hex_size">
        <div class="hexagon">
        </div>   
    </div>      
</div>
```

Result so far:
  [image]

I need a class to add to row to push the 2nd row up by 50%.Its seems to be over written by Bootstrap.

Comment: Post a fiddle or bootply, or at least include the relevant CSS for the non-bootstrap bits

Comment: the custom css has no margins or paddings set if i try to they have no effect other than on the shape..

Comment: Where are you declaring the custom CSS? after or before the bootstrap? as Ted said link to a fiddle would help....

Comment: Are you trying to push the bottom 2 hexagons between the 3 hexagons at the top? to make it look like a lattice?

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transform, like

```
.row.moveup{
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50px%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[See it in action here](http://www.bootply.com/hjqw6WBqkz)

(I made some minor edits to your html structure as well)

Also, you may want to have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062887/generate-repeating-hexagonal-pattern-with-css3)

Comment: Thanks, also the resources you provided were a better solution to what i was doing...

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's rows and cols come loaded with paddings and margins. So, I would suggest that you clear those (inline) to check whether this is a bootstrap issue or a conflict brought by your custom CSS. I am almost sure that the latter will be the issue.

Could you provide this post with a bit more information? Maybe we could be more helpful.