# Hexagon grid shapes (via transform) produces glitches in Safari (10.1 Mac OS)

Tags: html, css, macos, safari, css-transforms

I need a flexible, big hexagon grid, ideally

- in pure CSS (no pre-processing or JS shenanigans)
- hexagon dimensions in `percent`, so everything is nice and responsive

The solution I hacked together from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13069271/369707) is elegant and all, but produces really ugly glitches in Safari (10.1 on macOS 10.12.4), when zooming in our out (via `pinch to zoom` or `CMD +/-`).
The edges are all screwed up, and it takes a while to clear up, sometimes it doesn't clear up at all.

[image: render-error]

```css
html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #grid {
    /*otherwise there's some stuff running over to the right corner */
    /*TODO this stuff really should not be there*/
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    /*other gradients: #2196f3, #f44336 or: #d3959b, #bfe6ba (best) or: #5fc3e4, #e55d87*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #bfe9ff, #ff6e7f);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #bfe9ff, #ff6e7f);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #bfe9ff, #ff6e7f);
    /* For Fx 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(left, #bfe9ff, #ff6e7f);
    /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  }
  /**
   Hexagon Construction
   hexagons are here constructed by https://codepen.io/elbarto84/pen/wrcob
   For more reasons / alternatives, see here: https://github.com/maxheld83/accio/issues/84
   */

  .hex {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: calc(100% / 6.5 / 2);
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg)
                        skewY(30deg)
                        scaleX(0.866025403784439); /* sqrt(3)/2 */
    -ms-transform:      rotate(0deg)
                        skewY(30deg)
                        scaleX(0.866025403784439); /* sqrt(3)/2 */
    transform:          rotate(0deg)
                        skewY(30deg)
                        scaleX(0.866025403784439); /* sqrt(3)/2 */
    margin-top: calc(100% / 6.5 / 1.732050807568877 * -1/6.5); /* sqrt(2) */
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .hex:before, .hex:after {
    position: absolute;
    /* 86.6% = (sqrt(3)/2)*100% = .866*100% */
    top: 6.7%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 6.7%;
    left: 0; /* 6.7% = (100% -86.6%)/2 */
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1.154700538379252) /* 1.155 = 2/sqrt(3) */
                        skewY(-30deg)
                        rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform:      scaleX(1.154700538379252) /* 1.155 = 2/sqrt(3) */
                        skewY(-30deg)
                        rotate(-30deg);
    transform: scaleX(1.154700538379252) /* 1.155 = 2/sqrt(3) */
               skewY(-30deg)
               rotate(-30deg);
    background-color: white;
    content: '';
  }

  .hex-row {
    position: relative;
  }

  .hex-row:first-child {
    /*this weirdly acts only on first row and moves it down again to normal position*/
    margin-top: calc(100% / 6.5 / 1.732050807568877 * 1/6.5); /* sqrt(2) */
  }

  .hex-row:nth-child(even) {
    left: calc(100% / 13);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="hex-row">
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex-row">
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex hidden"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex-row">
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex-row">
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex-row">
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
      <div class="hex"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

---

**Is this somehow salvageable or is something fundamentally wrong with this design?**

I can basically use whatever design I want, I'd just prefer a single-div solution, and the design needs to be responsive (ideally in `percent`).