# Honeycomb structure or Polygon with react

Tags: css, reactjs, polygon

I'm working on a project, and I have n numbers of array also I've created a polygon with CSS & I'm rendering the array over polygon but the problem is I'm not getting any desirable results. can anybody please help me achieve this or share any beneficial resource links? I am unable to find any solution. Thanks in advance

Desirable result

[image: Here's the requirement]

&

what I've achieved.

[image: here's the outcome]

Here is hexagon code, & I'm looping over this flex

```
<Flex
    key={props.idx}
    justify="center"
    align="center"
    height="48px"
    width="42px"
    bg={
      props.selectedItems?.includes(props.number)
        ? "linear-gradient(97deg, #CD23E9 44.31%, #AC00FD 90.84%)"
        : "#FFC700"
    }
    clipPath="polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%)"
    cursor="pointer"
    onClick={() => {
      props.selectItem(props.number);
    }}
    onMouseOver={() => {
      setShowToolTip(props.number);
    }}
    onMouseOut={() => {
      setShowToolTip(-1);
    }}
  >
    <Text color="#fff" fontSize="10" fontWeight="600">
      {props.number}
    </Text>
  </Flex>
```

Comment: You forgot to provide the code

Comment: hey, just provided

Comment: From your approach with `Flex` you're going to need at least two additional pieces:  The even and odd rows are going to need some relative offset.  You can do this with a half-honeycomb which you show in your "desirable output" but do not have an implementation of.  You are also going to need to force the honeycomb outside of the `Flex` containers as they are just non-overlapping rows.  You may have to do some relative positioning on the honeycomb elements themselves.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75117555/8620333